# android making superscript text in textview got cutted

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

i have a layout containing multiple TextViews containing text with superscript... to make a portion superscript in text i have used `<sup>superscript text</sup>` tag in string.xml within text the problem here is my text got cutted in emulator view i have also tried to add padding but output is same nthing is working for it like , changing margin,padding,font size...please help here below is image what i get on emulator........

[image]

Comment: use android:padding="5dip" in your TextView (replace 5dip with your requirement)

Comment: i have told above in my question that i have tried to add padding but no change means even 20 brings no chnage getting same output

Comment: @SheerazKhan May I request to you please accept SKT's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Make it like this.
 < sup>< small>superscript text< /small>< /sup>

Answer (score 1):

A further problem remains: the superscripted text is *not* properly scaled, i.e. font size reduced.
So padding is just a weak solution to a bug in the proper rendering of a [super|sub]script.
I am investigating a fix for this...will see.

Answer (score 0):

if you want small superscript text than you can use

`<sup>< small>text< /small>< /sup>`

if you want to more small than you can use `<small>` tag twice like below

`<sup><small><small>text</small></small>< /sup>`