# Change size of superscript text

Tags: android, superscript

In my app, I want to have the dates displayed such as this:
[image]

For the same, I am using the suggestions which I found on Stackoverflow here:

[Option 1](https://github.com/fabiomsr/MoneyTextView)

[Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471508/change-font-of-superscript-text)

I tried Option 1 and this is the outcome:

[image]

The problem is that the 'th' is clearly too large but I could not find any way on how to adjust the size of the superscript text only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954040/android-making-superscript-text-in-textview-got-cutted/8968771)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set text on the textview through HTML Tag like this-

(Html.fromHtml("8<sup>th</sup>")

Comment: I think your answer doesn't answer the question. He wants to control the size of the superscript text.